# Android PreferenceFragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, xamarin, sharedpreferences

I have a MyPreferenceFragment that inherits from PreferenceFragmentCompat. This fragment resides inside a viewpager.

I want the preference screen to have 1 EditTextPreference, "Name", and two preferences which should open up a new preference screen, "Mobile" and "Email". However, while all 3 shows up correctly, clicking "Mobile" or "Email" does nothing. How do i get it to open a new screen? From the documentation it seems like this should happen automatically when nesting PreferenceScreen.

The xml file for this PreferenceFragment looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory 
  android:key="account_category" >
<android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference
  android:persistent="true"
  android:key="account_name" />

<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
  android:key="account_mobile_screen" >
  <android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference
    android:persistent="true"
    android:key="account_mobile" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>

<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
  android:key="account_email_screen" >
  <android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference
    android:persistent="true"
    android:key="account_email" />    
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>

  </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

So .. I needed to do something similar, I hope it helps if you still have the problem.

My SettingsFragment:

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Preferences;
using Android.Support.V7.Preferences;

namespace Aprepara.Droid.Activities.Fragments
{
    public class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat
    {

        private View _view;

        public override void OnCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, string rootKey)
        {
            //AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences);
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

In the settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/my_preferences_settings"/>
```

In the preference xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Category 1">

        <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:key="key1"
            android:title="Switch Preference"
            android:summary="Switch Summary"
            android:defaultValue="true" />

        <android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference
            android:key="key2"
            android:title="EditText Preference"
            android:summary="EditText Summary"
            android:dialogMessage="Dialog Message"
            android:defaultValue="Default value" />
        <android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="key3"
            android:title="CheckBox Preference"
            android:summary="CheckBox Summary"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
    </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ....
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/background3</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Folder structure of my project

[image]

I'm using the example https://www.codeday.top/2017/07/27/31411.html and https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-1-5959aa49337c

Finally, the result

[image]